# compile boost lib on cygwin, can't find header file in the same directory

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

```
$ ./b2 cxxflags='-std=gnu++11 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D"__MASABI_LONG(x)=(x)" -fpermissive'
..
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-11/release/threading-multi/pthread/once.o
libs\thread\src\pthread\once.cpp:8:10: fatal error: ./once_atomic.cpp: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "./once_atomic.cpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

    
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-11/release/threading-multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
libs\date_time\src\gregorian\greg_month.cpp:26:10: fatal error: greg_names.hpp: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "greg_names.hpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The compile error "greg_names.hpp: No such file or directory" is very odd, the header file greg_names.hpp actually is in libs\date_time\src\gregorian, same directory as greg_month.cpp
Same problem is for once_atomic.cpp..

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you including a `.cpp` file?

Comment: `libs\date_time\src\gregorian\greg_month.cpp:26:10: fatal error: greg_names.hpp: No such file or directory` Is this path present in the include paths?

Comment: @kiner_shah this include is inside the [boost source code](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/7f36ea346fcb1908c42683570c7196691fcdac95/src/pthread/once.cpp#L8)

Comment: Yes, it is boost source code.  "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -mthreads -m64 -std=gnu++11 -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS -D"__MASABI_LONG(x)=(x)" -fpermissive -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK=1 -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DDATE_TIME_INLINE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\gcc-11\release\threading-multi\gregorian\greg_month.o" "libs\date_time\src\gregorian\greg_month.cpp"  This is the compile cmd printed.

Comment: When adding -I"./libs/date_time/src/gregorian" , the compile passed. This means the code is OK, why gcc cannot find the header file located with the cpp file?